# redis scan command very slow

Tags: python-3.x, docker, redis

I have setup a redis cluster locally in a docker container using this [image](https://github.com/Grokzen/docker-redis-cluster). To start the redis cluster I run the following command: `docker run -e "IP=0.0.0.0" -p 7001-7005:7001-7005 -it grokzen/redis-cluster` and the redis cluster is started.

Now in a separate python file, I can successfully create the keys in the cluster and I can successfully fetch them using following, but occassionally only as sometimes it get stuck for minutes with nothing happening:

```py
startup_nodes = [{"host": "0.0.0.0", "port": 7001}]
connection = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, skip_full_coverage_check=True)
serializer = pa.default_serialization_context()

def get_value(connection, serializer, key):
    return serializer.deserialize(connection.get(key))

def set_value(connection, serializer, key, value):
    try:
        connection.set(key, serializer.serialize(value).to_buffer().to_pybytes())
        return True
    except:
        return False 
    
print(set_value(connection, serializer, key="test:ten", value="10"))

print(get_value(connection, serializer, key="test:ten"))
```

When I try to use the `scan` command: `connection.scan(cursor=0, match="test:*")`, it takes a lot of time (>10 mins) and nothing happens and I have to cancel the execution. Same is with when I use `connection.keys(pattern="test:*")`. I am pretty sure this is not expected behaviour and probably I am doing something wrong here, if someone can help that would be great.

Comment: Both `keys 'test:*'` and `scan 'test:*' 0` command could be very heavy command, specially when you have large Redis, under load, with multiple keys matching 'test:*' pattern. Also ,as I don't know much about Python just that it has different interpretation of `Exception` over than other `OOP language` likes `Java`, maybe an exception occured during executing your subroutine, e.g.: Redis connection is closed, or connection pool is exhausted or e.t.c.